# PowerShell - Rename folder

Tags: windows, powershell

I have folder like:

> [W][1234]Some[2019] 
> [W][123456]Some[2018] 
> [W][12345789]Some[2017] \

And I want to rename to

> [W]Some[2019] [1234] 
> [W]Some[2018] [123456] 
> [W]Some[2017] [12345789] 
> OR 
> Some[2017] [W] [12345789]

Will I find a program or a good person who will suggest a solution in powershell?

```
$BasePath = 'C:\test\'
$Find1 = '['
$Find2 = ']'

$Dir = Get-ChildItem -Path $BasePath -Filter '[*]*' -Recurse -Directory

foreach ($D in $Dir) {
   #Write-Host $D
   #Write-Host $D.FullName
   $DD = $D.Name.ToCharArray()
   foreach ($Char in $DD){
       if ($Char = '['){
           Write-Host 'Find char: ' $Char
#how count chars?
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Are those really the folder names (with the square brackets)? What have you tried yourself yet? What didn't work? Please show your code

Comment: Yes, really i have [number] name of. I try in powershell to find [ and ] and then i want to count char and paste in end
Code in post

Answer (score 0):

Square brackets in file or folder names need the use of parameter `-LiteralPath` for cmdlets like `Get-ChildItem` and `Rename-Item`. If you use `-Path`, these square brackets are taken as wildcard characters.

To create a new name from the old, you can use regex `-replace`

```
$BasePath = 'C:\test'

Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $BasePath -Filter '[*]*' -Recurse -Directory | ForEach-Object {
    $newName = $_.BaseName -replace '(\[\w+\])(\[\d+\])(.+)(\[\d+\])', '$1$3$4$2'
    Rename-Item -LiteralPath $_.FullName -NewName $newName -WhatIf
}
```

<sup>I have added switch `WhatIf` so you can first check what *would* happen. Take off that switch to actually rename the folders</sup>

Regex details

```
(           Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
   \[       Match the character “[” literally
   \w       Match a single character that is a “word character” (letters, digits, etc.)
      +     Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   ]        Match the character “]” literally
)          
(           Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 2
   \[       Match the character “[” literally
   \d       Match a single digit 0..9
      +     Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   ]        Match the character “]” literally
)          
(           Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 3
   .        Match any single character that is not a line break character
      +     Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)          
(           Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 4
   \[       Match the character “[” literally
   \d       Match a single digit 0..9
      +     Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   ]        Match the character “]” literally
)
```